# Apache - exposing webapp on port using subdomain / route with SSL

Tags: apache2, subdomain, http-proxy

I'm trying to expose web app via subdomain with SSL or via route.

**Subdomain Method:**

The webapp I'm running is on port: http://localhost:4567/

With the following configuration, the web browser tells me the app is "not secure" (non-https).

The app is generally working fine, but is non-https.

What am I doing wrong?
Are there alternative configurations?

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blast.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://blast.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin me@gmail.com
    ServerName blast.example.com
    # ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
#    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4567/
#    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4567/

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:4567/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4567/
  </Location>

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL

  SSLCertificateFile ...
  SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

I had been following the prescription given at [How to configure multiple subdomain with SSL in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503828/how-to-configure-multiple-subdomain-with-ssl-in-apache/38510400)

**Path/Route Method**

I had also tried exposing the app as a route path (ie https://example.com/blast)

```
  <Location /blast/ >
    ProxyPass http://localhost:4567/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4567/
  </Location>
```

but the reverse proxy didn't see to work in that, if I started with:

```
https://example.com/blast
```

And clicked whatever on the start page.
The app would generate a internal URL without the /blast part, resulting in 404:

```
https://example.com/blah-blah-generated-url 
(should be https://example.com/blast/blah-blah-generated-url)
```

In general, the subdomain path seems to work better except for the non-https problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Setting up a path/route:**

Making the application accessible with https://example.com/blast.  If the application generates new routes, ProxyPassReverse is needed; otherwise; only ProxyPass is needed.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ...
  ProxyPass "/blast/" "http://localhost:4567/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/blast/" "/"
  ...
```

Found in Example 1, here: [ProxyPassReverse doesn't rewrite Location (http header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454271/proxypassreverse-doesnt-rewrite-location-http-header)